# Quickmarks (:qmarks) not saving in Pentadactyl

Tags: firefox, pentadactyl

-Pentadactyl v1.1 (upd-2014-03-26)
-Firefox 28

supposedly qmark is persistent across browser sessions, but not in my case. I'll add a qmark e.g.

:qmark g mail.google.com

upon ff exit the qmark is no longer available.

Comment: Works for me on Pentadactyl hg7067 (2014/03/10) running on FF 28.0.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem too. It was happening because the directory where quick marks are supposed to be saved didn't exist. To find out where this is on your system run this is pentadactyl command:

```
:js alert(storage.infoPath.path)
```

Just create this folder and quick marks should become persistent.

For example, on linux

```
mkdir -p ~/.pentadactyl/info/default
```

on windows

```
mkdir %USERPROFILE%\pentadactyl\info\default
```